# Armadillo: non-contiguous views of arma::subview

Tags: c++, armadillo

is there any way to use a non-contiguous view of a matrix

i.e. like in

```
arma::mat A = arma::zeros(3,3);
arma::uvec idx = {0,2};
A(idx,idx) += 2;
```

but using a subview of matrix A?

i.e.

```
arma::subview<double> swA = A.submat(0,0,2,2);
swA(idx,idx) += 2.5;
```

this last bit doesn't compile as

```
 error: no match for call to ‘(arma::subview<double>) (arma::uvec&, arma::uvec&)’    
swA(idx,idx) += 2.5;
```

Just to give a bit of context which could help I'm using the `arma::subviewc`s as arguments to functions. Since `A.submat(0,0,2,2)` is an `rtype` I cannot pass it to a functions as a non-const argument and inside the function I need to be able to access the elements in a non non-contiguous way.

A minimal (non-working) example too see what I mean could be the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

void f(arma::subview<double> x)
{ 
  arma::uvec i = {0,2};
  arma::uvec j = {1,2};
  x(i,j)  += 2.5;
}

int main ()
{

  arma::mat A = arma::zeros(5,5);
  std::cout << A << std::endl;

  f(A.submat(0,0,2,2));
  std::cout << A << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

where gcc returns again

```
 error: no match for call to ‘(arma::subview<double>) (arma::uvec&, arma::uvec&)’
```

The silly thing to solve this is to copy the matrix, pass it as a reference and then copy back to A:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

void f(arma::mat& x)
{ 
  arma::uvec i = {0,2};
  arma::uvec j = {1,2};
  x(i,j)  += 2.5;
}

int main ()
{

  arma::mat A = arma::zeros(5,5);
  std::cout << A << std::endl;

  arma::mat B = A.submat(0,0,2,2);
  f(B);
  A.submat(0,0,2,2) = B;
  std::cout << A << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which compiles and run perfectly, but I NEED to avoid copying the matrix at all costs (A is much much bigger than 5x5!)

Again to be clear, I cannot do the following

```
[...]
void f(arma::mat& x)
{ 
  arma::uvec i = {0,2};
  arma::uvec j = {1,2};
  x(i,j)  += 2.5;
}
[...]
f(A.submat(0,0,2,2));
```

as the subview would be an `rtype` and I'd get  from gcc

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘arma::mat& {aka arma::Mat<double>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘arma::mat {aka arma::Mat<double>}
```

Am I in troubles (only an implementation issue and is not on the TODO list of the developers) or is there an elegant solution from someone smarter then I am?

Thanks!

*sidenotes*:

- *I am open to change the linear algebra library to others (e.g. Eigen or whatever) if doing things like this is trivial there, but I'd rather not since I've been using armadillo for years now and I've been always very satisfied...*
- *I am aware of the possibility of using loops and simpler subviews to get the same result in the simpler code I've shown, but the real code is more complex and this subviews are to be used in matrix operations, so I'd have to loop **and copy** the submatrix in a temporary object, which I'd like to avoid*

Comment: Maybe write a patch which implements the functionality and send it to Armadillo developers?

Comment: I needed such a functionality too. My only way to avoid this was doing some nasty pointer arithmetics and modifying the values directly. but this is not as fast as reordering the values and doing matrix operations. Is there maybe someone else with a better approach?

Answer (score -1):

he/she/it uses a different class (`subview`) when you call the method `arma::matrix<T >operator()` on a matrix....and as you find (and me as I come here for answer) this is an Rvalue so it can not be referenced...but element of the class `arma::matrix<T>` could be initialized by an object of class subview (so why they don't create an access function to use subview as lvalue?, why they even create the class subview for?)...I think they can solve this with some template and `Move()`, but from the bottom inherited up to the upper calsses like `arma::mat`. 
(the problem you request for happens not only on sparse matrix, even on dense matrix, it works only if you put `f(const arma:mat& )` but you can't modify it)

solution: nothing, I tried with std::move() to trick the rvalue of subview to an empty matrix, benchamarking the time to exec a loop of these 3 for 100000 times;

/*******************************1**********************/

```
void f(arma::mat &B)
{
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int func()
{
  arma::mat A = arma::zeros(50,50);
  //std::cout <<"A:\n"<< A << std::endl;

  arma::uvec i = arma::regspace<arma::uvec>( 0, 1, 10);
  arma::uvec j = arma::regspace<arma::uvec>( 0, 1, 10);
  unsigned p=1;
  do{
    arma::mat B=A(i,j);
    f(B);
    A(i,j)= B;
    p++;
  }while(p<100000);
  return 0;
}
```

/**************************2***********************/

```
void f(arma::mat &B)
{
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int func2()
{
  arma::mat A = arma::zeros(50,50);
  arma::uvec i = arma::regspace<arma::uvec>( 0, 1, 10);
  arma::uvec j = arma::regspace<arma::uvec>( 0, 1, 10);
  unsigned p=1;
  arma::mat B;
  do{
    B=A(i,j);
    f(B);
    A(i,j) = B;
    p++;
  }while(p<100000);
  return 0;
}
```

/************************3**********************/

```
void f(arma::mat &B)
{
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int func3()
{
  arma::mat A = arma::zeros(50,50);
  arma::uvec i = arma::regspace<arma::uvec>( 0, 1, 10);
  arma::uvec j = arma::regspace<arma::uvec>( 0, 1, 10);
  unsigned p=1;
  arma::mat B;
  do{
    B=std::move(A(i,j));
    f(B);
    A(i,j)= std::move(B);
    p++;
  }while(p<100000);
  return 0;
}
```

compiling and launching from R shows no difference from constructor copy or std::move(). tried even with `arma::mat B(std::move(A(i,j))` no difference, time identical to `func()` (little higher than `func2()` and `func3()` due to variable declaration).

```
  Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  func() 20.56159 20.68200 21.22679 20.98329 21.55746 27.62831  1000   b
 func2() 19.21450 19.37398 19.88782 19.66397 20.14731 27.86020  1000  a 
 func3() 19.19892 19.37547 19.89098 19.67835 20.17973 27.19525  1000  a
```

this seems to be the fastest (as previously A(i,j)= std::move(B) puts B to 0 size and need reallocation when B= A(i,j)):

```
arma::mat B;
  do{
    B=std::move(A(i,j));
    f(B);
    A(i,j)= B;
    p++;
  }while(p<100000);
  return 0;
```

same benchmark

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 func4() 19.22223 19.30687 19.3907 19.33198 19.36293 23.20771  1000
```

`std::move(A(i,j))` seems not to affect (not loose the content of) matrix A as A(i,j) is an r-value of subview, not the matrix itself.